# Laravel 3: Run migrations on production server / in .php file

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I have been working with Laravel 3 on my local server. I have been using terminal and Artisan to perform my migrations.

I want to install my site on my production server, but I want to create a sort of 'install/migration' script that will perform all the migrations and guide a user through configuration.

I have found where all migration methods are (used by artisan) but I'm struggling to use them. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confusing some things (I'm not sure, so I'll tell just in case).

**Migrations are meant for developers.** Your end users don't run migrations directly. So migrations are for you and your fellow developers. If you want your users to run migrations, than you just create a normal page and have some link or a button that the user presses and this will run an action (a function) on your controller (if you have routes set up this way). In this function, *you* should run the migration.

**Running migrations from PHP:** you can use the Command class to run tasks.

```
Command::run(array('migrate'));
```

This will run the migrate task, obviously.
Is this what you're after?

Comment: Thanks - yes that is what I was after. Maybe I hadn't explained properly. I will setup the migrations, but when installing a site on a  production server, I want a script that will run all the migrations. Will try out your code and let you know if that does the trick.

Comment: Great - thats works. Have updated your answer as needed to add some more code to get it to work.

Comment: I got the notification that I got a code suggestion, but I can't see where I can accept them and see them (see my screenshot: http://demo.ddesign.si/temp/so.png).

Comment: you don't have enough points. Just copy what I wrote and add it your answer

Comment: @Gaz_Edge, i am here to look for this solution as well. i think u just update it on your question there will do :)